# How do I speed bridge up on Bedwars?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-bedwars

I'm trying to get good at Bedwars, and one of the main things that is allowing people to get the advantage over me is that they can bridge up faster than I can, thus easily getting the high ground.  I'm good at normal speed bridging, I can do it fast and consistently (using the ninja bridge method, shifting and unshifting), but I can't figure out how to do it when bridging up.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a pattern that you have to get used to.

Hold the S key, shift on the edge of a block, place a block backwards and unshift, and jump up and place a block up, and then repeat.

All of this would be done in less than a quarter of a second with micro adjustments to keep proper spacing as well, but it gets much easier by just doing it more by practicing.

Comment: can I go faster than pillaring doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by pillaring? Like pillaring up?...

Comment: yes that's what i mean.  I am trying to judge when it's best to use this technique vs pillaring if I need to beat someone.  Also, is it possible to do this while holding A and S keys?

Comment: I've been using this method and it is possible to do it while holding A and S which makes it fast and convenient. =D